# Sending an email depending on % records that have a certain value

Tags: php, mysql, email

Is it possible to have either MySQL or PHP send an email when a % of people listed in a MySQL database have responded to a question.

For example, I have 500 people listed in a MySQL DB, they are invited to take part in a short survey, each time a person completed their record is updated to reflect they have completed.  What I'm looking for is a way of MySQL or some PHP script to send me an email when, say 10% have responded to the survey.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far - before embarking upon coding, I wanted to get a sense if it was possible.  Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: You'll notice that I'm not asking for code, code examples or for someone to do this for me.  I'm trying to understand if the concept is possible and whether MySQL or PHP would be the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a trigger and connect to a table with results.
If user complete record, add a record (using this trigger)  to a mail queue table (an example with status "not processed").

Create a cronjob that checks mail queue table for "not processed" records and execute calculation, then send email.
You can send email from PHP only and not from Mysql directly.

Comment: Thanks Dian - appreciate that.